# Is there a list of all known national official typefaces?

Tags: typefaces, identity

Most countries have an 'official' typeface(s) that they use as part of their identity guidelines in promoting the government or typesetting legislation.

For example, all UK statutes are typeset by the Queen's Printer in Book Antiqua (ie Palatino), while gov.uk makes use of a variation of the Transport typeface.  Canada specifies Helvetica as its standard typeface.  The EU (obviously not a country) uses a variant of Albertina in its official journal.

Is there a reasonably comprehensive list of these sort of official typeface choices across different countries? It would be quite interesting to compare if such a thing does exist.

Comment: Wikipedia has a [List of public signage typefaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_public_signage_typefaces)

Comment: Mind that I wouldn’t expect a reasonable country to use one typeface throughout. For example, the requirements on typefaces for signage and laws are quite different.